# Creating a non-selectable option with System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox in Powershell

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm creating a script that allows for selecting email addresses from a dropdown in Powershell.  I'm trying to find a way to have the top option not be selectable.  I tried just having text above the dropdown, but I wasn't able do that either (if someone knows how to do that that would work for this as well).

This is what I have so far:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$emailForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$emailForm.ClientSize = '400,200'
$emailForm.Text = "Select Email Address"
$emailForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$emailForm.KeyPreview = $true
$emailForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -ieq "Escape") {
        $emailForm.Close()
    }
})

$emailList = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$emailList.Text = ""
$emailList.Width = 270
$emailList.AutoSize = $true
$emailList.Items.Insert(0, "--- Please Select Email ---")

@(
    'email1@fqdn.tld',
    'email2@fqdn.tld'
) | ForEach-Object {
    [void] $emailList.Items.Add($_)
}

$emailList.SelectedIndex = 0
$emailList.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(50,50)
$emailList.Font = [System.Drawing.Font]::New("Microsoft Sans Serif", 10)
$emailForm.Controls.Add($emailList)

$emailButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$emailButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(255,100)
$emailButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(65,30)
$emailButton.Text = "Select"

$emailForm.Add_KeyDown({
    if ($_.KeyCode -ieq "Enter") {
        $emailButton.PerformClick()
    }
})
$emailButton.Add_Click({
    $script:emailSelect = $emailList.SelectedItem
    $emailForm.Close()
})
$emailForm.Controls.Add($emailButton)

[void] $emailForm.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$emailList.Text = "--- Please Select Email ---"` and
remove/comment up the following lines:

- `### $emailList.Items.Insert(0, "--- Please Select Email ---")`
- `### $emailList.SelectedIndex = 0`

Add basic validity check to the `$emailButton.Add_Click` as follows:

```
$emailButton.Add_Click({
    ### validity check BEGIN
    if ($emailList.SelectedIndex -lt 0) {
        return $false
    }
    ### validity check END
    $script:emailSelect = $emailList.SelectedItem
    $emailForm.Close()
})
```

Then, updated code snippet should work as intended…

Comment: That works great, but now I've noticed that the "Select" button has now vanished when I update the `$emailButton.Add_Click` code block.  Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Nevermind.  I inadvertently removed `$emailForm.Controls.Add($emailButton)` when updating the code.  I put it back and it works correctly now.  Thanks for the help!